# Camera background image not visible through transparent cloth

Tags: camera, image, transparency, cloth-simulation

I have a simple cloth simulation that I want to export as a video.
A background image is setup from within the camera.
The problem is:
The flag is suppossed to be slighty translusent but the background image will not be visible through the translucent object the area will become more and more gray the higher the translucency.
I am useing Eevee and Alpha Blend, changing the blending mode does not work as Opaque causes artifacts witht he shadows and stay completely opaque until turning Fac up to 1.0.
Alpha Clip will keep the image completely opaque until Fac is at 0.5 then it will becom 100% translucent.
Alpha Hash does make the flag translucent and the background image visible but gives a very grainy low quality cloth.

Here is the problem with Fac at 1.0 to highlight the issue:
[image: Fac set to 1.0 to highlight problem]
[image: Nodes]
[image: Material]
[image: Camera]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is simply a viewport issue in the rendering its perfectly translucent with the image visible.